# Can we import SQL from S3 bucket to AWS ec2 (instance)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, import

I'm trying to import a SQL file from S3 bucket to EC2 instance.

The SQL file is publicly accessible and with the help of mysql client installed in the instance I'm executing the following command.

```
mysql> source https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{sql-file}
```

When I do I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{sql-file}', error: 2
```

I'm not an expert, but is it possible what I'm trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably do this in one step.  You have to download the file, then load the local (downloaded) copy into MySQL.

```
$ wget https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/{sql-file} -O some-local-filename.sql

$ mysql [options]

mysql> source some-local-filename.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

What about not downloading the file, but directly pushing into the MySQL DB ?

```
aws s3 cp s3://'<bucket name>'/'<database name>'.sql.gz - | gunzip | mysql
    --host=127.0.0.1 \
    --user='<user name>' \
    --password='<password>' \
    --port=3306
```

or,

```
aws s3 cp s3://'<bucket name>'/'<database name>'.sql - | mysql
    --host=127.0.0.1 \
    --user='<user name>' \
    --password='<password>' \
    --port=3306
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a long procedure to do so, The best details are given by AWS themself. Please read

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: These instructions are specific to SQL Server.