# database backup form RDS to S3 saves empty backup sql.gz files - How to Troubleshoot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

overview about the issue.

- An RDS cluster is setup with two RDS instances (rdslab0 and rdslab1) where rdslab0 is used as a read replica of rdslab1.
- In addition to RDS backups, selective database dumps are executed from an EC2 instance via root’s crontab (crontab -l) using mysqldump statements.
- The shell script running these backups on a nightly basis is stored at /root/db-backup.sh. 'db' is a database on this mysql RDS instance.
- The script contains several mysqldump statements when run will save the mysql .sql.gz backup dump files to a s3 bucket “backups”.
- **The script ran well until a week ago but then started saving empty files since a few days.** As of now in S3, db-schema-backups, db-database-backups folders have those respective mysqldump .sql.gz files saved but the files don’t contain any real backup content.
- I’m not sure if this is an issue with mysqldump statement, IAM permissions, or DB permissions or something else but the files are being saved empty. For example the backup files are being saved in Bytes instead of their actual sizes in KBs and MBs.

db-backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#  Dump the db database from the RDS readreplica and move it to S3.
#  Dump the db database from the RDS readreplica and move it to S3.
#  S3 Bucket has policy access to only allow db-backup IAM User PutObject
#  mysqlbackup is used to backup files

bucketName="backups"
today=$(date +%d)
endPoint2="database-endpoint"

#All databases, routines, procedures, etc
mysqldump db --routines --triggers | gzip > /root/db-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
aws --profile db-backup s3 cp /root/db-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz s3://dbaccount-backups/db-database-backups/
aws --profile db-backup s3api put-object-tagging --bucket $bucketName --key db-database-backups/db-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=retention,Value=60}]'
rm /root/db-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz

#Schema backups
mysqldump db --no-data  | gzip > /root/db-schema-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
aws --profile db-backup s3 mv /root/db-schema-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz s3://dbaccount-backups/db-schema-backups/
aws --profile db-backup s3api put-object-tagging --bucket $bucketName --key db-schema-backups/db-schema-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=retention,Value=14}]'
```

Comment: As files are getting saved to `S3`, there are high chances, there is no issue `IAM` role with `S3` and code that push files to `S3`. There may be problem with your `ec2` instance where this `crontab` is running and doing `mysqldump`, though there is no error you have mentioned, hence its hard to answer the question, but it may be possible that instance has `no space left`, hence when `mysqldump` it creates blank files without data, as there is no space on the instance.

Comment: You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425766/2732674 to directly upload to S3 instead of manual downloading to your machine.

Comment: I figured it out. I manually ran the shell script (we can also try debug mode) and checked the errors.it is a db view that is stopping the script from dumping everything.

`mysqldump: Got error: 1356: View 'xxxxlist' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them when using LOCK TABLES.`
Thank you.